# Xaml reference static properties like System.Windows.Media.Colors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm defining a custom palette class in a similar way to the inbuilt System.Windows.Media.Colors static class.

Ideally I would like to reference this in a similar way to the Colors class. e.g.

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
```

The most concise version I have so far is:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{x:Static Palette:PrimaryPalette.Red}"/>
```

Also my PrimaryPalette class has properties with a return type SolidColorBrush rather than Color.

So my question is two fold

1. Is there a more concise method of referencing a custom color set?
2. Is the inbuilt Colors class special within the framework or is there some way of creating a class which operates in similar fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If verbosity and ease-of-use is your primary concern then I would recommend using a custom MarkupExtension:

```
public class CustomColor : MarkupExtension
{
    [ConstructorArgument("Key")]
    public object Key { get; set; }

    public CustomColor()
    {
    }

    public CustomColor(object key)
    {
        this.Key = key;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        try
        {
            var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(this.Key.ToString()); 
            return new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }
    }

}
```

By following the tips on [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and) you can also add the namespace for this extension to the XAML processor which in turn allows you to use it like this:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{CustomColor Blue}"  />
```

This is just one way of doing things, in this particular example I'm simply parsing the key string and converting it to a color, but you can replace that with any key type and/or conversion code you want.

Comment: This is brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to be of help. One very important thing I forgot to mention: if you do intend to use a custom extension without having to declare the namespace then you'll need to place it in it's own class library project. No idea why but others have encountered it as well, seems to be a bug in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Marks answer is the correct answer I just thought I would share my usage which is slightly different than Marks but only due to my specific needs.

In my case I wanted a set of new colours to be able to be selected by name so to achieve this I utilised a dictionary

```
public class PrimaryPalette : MarkupExtension
{
    public static Dictionary<PrimaryPaletteColours, Color> Palette => 
        new Dictionary<PrimaryPaletteColours, Color>
        {
            { PrimaryPaletteColours.CustomMagenta,    Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xDA, 0x42, 0xAA) },
            { PrimaryPaletteColours.CustomBlue,       Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x11, 0x42, 0xFF) },
            { PrimaryPaletteColours.CustomGreen,      Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x33, 0xDE, 0x60) },
            { PrimaryPaletteColours.CustomOrange,     Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xDA, 0x80, 0x22) },
            { PrimaryPaletteColours.CustomPurple,     Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xCC, 0x00, 0xFF) },
            { PrimaryPaletteColours.CustomRed,        Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xEE, 0x42, 0x00) },
            { PrimaryPaletteColours.CustomTurqoise,   Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x10, 0xAB, 0xBC) },
            { PrimaryPaletteColours.CustomGold,       Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xDA, 0xA0, 0x22) }
        };

    public PrimaryPalette() { }

    public PrimaryPalette(PrimaryPaletteColours key) { Key = key; }

    [ConstructorArgument("Key")]
    public PrimaryPaletteColours Key { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        try
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Palette[Key]);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }
    }
}

public enum PrimaryPaletteColours
{
    CustomMagenta,
    CustomBlue,
    CustomGreen,
    CustomOrange,
    CustomPurple,
    CustomRed,
    CustomTurqoise,
    CustomGold
}
```

After the namespace tweak Mark suggested my usage is:

```
{PrimaryPalette CustomMagenta}
```

This method also gives you intellisense and compile time verification to ensure the color name is correct.